# PHP : simple regex problem

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Some of my HTML files contains string like :

```
{foreach $any_kind_of_charaters}
Any kind of string including "\n\r" and spaces here
{/foreach}
```

I want to apply `PHP's preg_match_all` on them and wanna return a nice `array` like printed below

```
Array
(
    [0] => {foreach $any_kind_of_charaters}
            Any kind of string including "\n\r" and spaces here
           {/foreach}
    [1] => any_kind_of_charaters
    [2] => Any kind of string including "\n\r" and spaces here
)
```

This REGEX : `/\{foreach\s+\$(.*)\}\s+(.*)\s+\{\/foreach\}/` working okay for me,
but it fails when i add new lines(\n) between `{foreach}{/foreach}` tags.

You help will be much appreciated, thanks.

**ARRAY AFTER USING "S" MODIFIER**

```
Array
(
    [0] => {foreach $any_kind_of_charaters}
        Any kind of string including "\n\r" and spaces here
        {/foreach}
    [1] => any_kind_of_charaters}
        Any kind of string including "\n\r" and spaces here
    [2] => 
)
```

Look `second key` of the `array` contain unnecessary data, and `last key` of `array` is totally empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `s` modifier flag on your regular expression.

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

---

Like this: `/\{foreach\s+\$(.*)\}\s+(.*)\s+\{\/foreach\}/s` <- note the modifier

Comment: try removing the `\s` since now a dot will match that too. Also try the `m` modifier.

Comment: no luck with `m` modifier, and the array become more ugly after replacing `\s` to `.`